# Dropdown for each cell in tabular data

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a very large html table that is similar to the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>value1</td>
        <td>value2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>value3</td>
        <td>value4</td>
    </tr>   
</table>
```

For each value I need to have a dropdown, where a user can click to change the value. This would trigger an ajax function. What would be the best way to do this? A dropdown in each ? One dropdown that changes position? How should i go about adding this?

Comment: Are you only asking which approach should be used to add the dropdowns? What are your concerns about one approach over the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This solution](http://jsfiddle.net/m6AJn/5/) changes the cell to a dropdown when clicked, and back to a cell when a value is selected, just in case this was desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to this, I would assume. :) I used jQuery. :)

```
$("tr").each(function(){
    $("td").each(function(){
        var before = $(this).text();
        $(this).html("<select><option>"+before+"</option></select>");
    });
});​
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/transparent/m6AJn/)

Comment: This would add a select element to each cell, but it would only have a single option to choose from. The problem is more complicated than this. Though what the OP is asking isn't clear either.

Comment: Yeah, I've been trying to improve it, just in case the OP meant something else. I came to the conclusion that perhaps the user wanted each tr to be a dropdown and the tds are the options. :)

Answer (score 1):

Some of this depends on the experience you want for the user, but I would lean towards putting a select element in each table cell. You can then have the select hidden until the user selects one of the values to change, or you can have the select elements visible the entire time. This is easier because you can put the values into the select box before the browser renders the page. If this is not usable, for example, if the browser has trouble rendering the page because of the size of the markup, then you could move to using a single select element.

If you use a single select box, that would require you to move it around to the correct cell, and also determine how to get the possible values into the select box. You could use a data attribute on your td tags to store the data, or you could make an ajax call. But that could be chatty if you go back to the server each time a cell needs to be edited. Basically this would be the harder option to get right.

Start with the simple way (select in each td). And if that proves to be problematic, move on to the harder one. That is what I would do.

Comment: I wouldn't think it'd matter too much, but one should also keep SEO in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I got it working. This is an alternative to my other answer. 
This gets each tr to be a dropdown and the tds are the options. I used jQuery.

```
$("tr").each(function(i){   
    $("td").each(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith("<option>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
    });
    $(this).replaceWith("<select>"+$(this).html()+"</select>");    
});
```

​
[Updated jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/transparent/m6AJn/)